# Creating a material similar to the art style of Gareth Davies @spudonkey

Tags: node-editor

I am working in blender to create assets and sprite sheets for a project i'm coding for school. I was going for a pixel art look until I stumbled across the work by Spudonkey. I'm looking at shadeless texturing and vector painting.(Probably going to be much flatter in colour than the work below). I just want your input on what node setup, engine and if its possible to get away with little splashes of colour and scratches without painting textures. My model is currently under 11000 tris, this is why i want to avoid textures because of sharp edges.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, you can try Edge nodes. http://blendernpr.org/edge-node-v1-2-4-july-2015/
I haven't tried it  myself but I think you can get the result you want. 
If that seems too much of a hassle (which it probably is), I've managed to get the colors to be passable as an imitation. Of course you would have to improve this greatly. Here is the setup: [image: Setup]

Play around with the noise and the mapping nodes to get diffirent color splashes. Also, it might be necessary for you to play with the Light path node in case the emmision shader's light is shown in other elements in your scene.
Hope this helps a little

Comment: Great help thank you. I would recommend this for a camouflage pattern or something similar

Comment: Where should I place my light path node?